# how can I develop a class for searching OID values with SNMP4j

Tags: java, snmp4j

I am preparing to develop an application for monitoring network traffic specifically the SNMP protocol.  In my research, I have discovered the Java API SNMP4j, but I am confused about how to begin. Does anyone have a tutorial to help me, specifically with searching OID values?